# Changing the action name in routeconfig

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to replace the default action name with some random string.

For instance in the code below I am doing this for the controller name and it works :

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "test",
               url: "randomstring/{action}",//this works
               defaults: new { controller = "WorkRoles", action = "DisplayListOfRolesUser", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

I am simply trying to do the same for the action name, so in the URL i have something like `site.com/changed-action-name`

Is this achiavable with routing?

Can someone help?

Comment: Sure. What is the issue you are having?

Comment: when I try something like {action}/newactioname it won't work as I'd like it to.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @I ilustrated under the snippet what I want to achieve and in the comment above yours I described how I tried to achieve it, i.e. url: "{action}/newActionName",.

Comment: what is newActionName ? {action} will take you to action so why use newActionName?

Answer (score 0):

you mean this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "changed-action-name",
                defaults: new { controller = "WorkRoles", action = "DisplayListOfRolesUser", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

this will take me to action `DisplayListOfRolesUser` and controller `WorkRoles` whenever i enter `site.com/changed-action-name`